# Caching generated images with Sinatra, MiniMagick & nginx

Tags: nginx, imagemagick, sinatra, minimagick, sinatra-assetpack

I'm building a placeholder image site - similar enough to http://placekitten.com/

I've got a quick & dirty version working with a directory of big images, and a Sinatra route that randomises the image selection & resizes it to the right dimensions.

```
get '/p/:width' do
  width = params[:width].to_i
  path = Dir.glob('raw/top100/*.jpg').shuffle[0]
  image = ImageResizer.new(path)
  image.width= width
  content_type("image/#{image.image_format}")
  image.to_s
end
```

- this ImageResizer class https://gist.github.com/EvilScott/2431343#file-image_resizer-rb

This works but is a bit crappy - what's the best way to make it a little bit scalable before I link to it? I've heard about nginx caching but never done it before (& can't see how to fit it in with the images I'm generating) - or should I just pre-generate a bunch of different sizes when I add images to the server and cache those?

Thanks